# Kendo grid filter number formating after filtered

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, formatting, grid

I enter a number 614789 into the kendo grid filter column and click filter.
When I open the filter up again it displays the number as 614,789.00.  How do I format the filter to display the 614789 format?
[Image is of the kendo column filter that states: "Show items with value that: 'Is equal to' 617,353.00].

I am using a model to with item number as int?

```
namespace PitchList.Models {public int? ItemNum { get; set; }

public ActionResult PitchList_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
        string salesReps, int? custNum, int? custName, int? genericSource, int? noSalesDate
        , int? programs, int? lastSearched)
    {
        IEnumerable<PitchListViewModel> data = new List<PitchListViewModel>();

        if (custNum != null || custName != null)
        {
            data = pl.Read(salesReps, custNum, custName, genericSource,
                    noSalesDate, programs, lastSearched);
        }


        return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: It looks like your image did not attach properly. Also, you should always provide a description of the images you post.

Answer (score 0):

For each field in the Kendo Grid you should be able to specify a format

```
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [ {
        field: "date",
        format: "{0: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"
      }, {
        field: "number",
        format: "{0:c}"
      },
 {
        field: "number",
        format: "{0:######}"
      } ],
      filterable: true,
      dataSource: [ { date: new Date(), number: 3.1415 } ]
    });
    </script>
```

In your case use the format {0:000000} or {0:######}

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt.  I am using .Format("{0:######}" (kendo MVC) in the grid field, but the filter still formats to #,###.00

Comment: Can you edit your question and put in the call you are making to kendoGrid? Also, make sure your data that you are binding to the grid is coming in as numbers and not strings.